# coursera assignment python file compiling error

Tags: python, tensorflow

i have a coursera assignment in jupyter notebook the problem is that in jupyter it runs correctly but when i submit it fail and shows this error :
Can't compile the student's code. invalid syntax (student_solution.py, line 23)

the task is :
In this exercise you'll try to build a neural network that predicts the price of a house according to a simple formula.

So, imagine if house pricing was as easy as a house costs 50k + 50k per bedroom, so that a 1 bedroom house costs 100k, a 2 bedroom house costs 150k etc.

How would you create a neural network that learns this relationship so that it would predict a 7 bedroom house as costing close to 400k etc.

Hint: Your network might work better if you scale the house price down. You don't have to give the answer 400...it might be better to create something that predicts the number 4, and then your answer is in the 'hundreds of thousands' etc.

my answer was

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow import keras
def house_model(y_new):
   xs = np.array([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0, 11.0, 12.0, 13.0], dtype=float)
   ys = np.array([100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 250.0, 300.0, 350.0, 450.0, 500.0, 550.0,600.0, 650.0,700.0], dtype=float)

   model = tf.keras.Sequential([keras.layers.Dense(units=1, input_shape=[1])])
   model.compile(optimizer='sgd',loss='mean_squared_error')
   model.fit(xs,ys,epochs=500)

   return (model.predict(y_new)[0]+1) //100
prediction = house_model([7.0])
print(prediction)
```

Comment: Is the indentation of your code above the same as in your submission? Please check.

Comment: there is indentation in the lines from 5 to 10 and the rest is just the same

Comment: Please edit your question to correct it.

Comment: So what is the error message that you are getting?

Comment: when i run the code in jupyter it works correctly without any error but when i submit in coursera it says that my answer is incorrect  and show this message :Can't compile the student's code. invalid syntax (student_solution.py, line 23)

Comment: Given that your code snippet above does not have 23 lines, can you please indicate which line is causing the problem?

Comment: line 4 where def house_model(y_new):

Comment: @eyabaklouti  how do you solved this problem??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just remove the last two blocks of JavaScript. It worked for me.

Comment: Please be specific - what JavaScript are you referring to?

Comment: I face the same problem can you explain more ?

Comment: I can confirm this works, although I am a bit mystified as to why. The JavaScript referred to is the two blocks at the end of the notebook that start with "%%javascript".  Seems like there may be a mismatch between how Jupyter parses that sort of block and how the grader does.

Answer (score 0):

Try Commenting out the last part of the code 5th and 6th Cell in the notebook which is not the part of your submission.

Comment: here is a link of my work https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zzqCouah-vPWHwykQOmBY_jdTHwbpOUe/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

The issue happened to me when I used Jupyter magics such as `%%time` in a code cell, so you could try removing such Jupyter magics if you have any.

Answer (score 0):

When providing ys values (100.0,150.0..) rather use tenth scale like (1.0,1.5...)
And in the next block you can do as follows:

```
   prediction = house_model([7.0])
   print(prediction*100)
```

Gladly, It worked for Me.

Answer (score 0):

Pls change `ys` data in your code to this

```
xs = np.array([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0, 11.0, 12.0, 13.0], dtype=float)
   
ys = np.array([1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5, 3.0, 3.5, 4.5, 5.0, 5.5,6.0, 6.5,7.0], dtype=float)
```